# Double integral of symmetric function

Tags: mathematical-physics

Can someone please derive and explain how the LHS is equal to the RHS using the fact that the function $f$ is symmetrical with respect to time variables $t_1$ and $t_2$. Here $t$ is some constant.

$\int_{0}^{t}dt_1 \int_{0}^{t} dt_2 f(t_2-t_1)  = 2 \int_{0}^{t}dt_1 \int_{0}^{t_1} f(k) dk$

Comment: Please use formatting correctly

Comment: Please present the question in explicit form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f: t\mapsto f(t)$ as such is not "symmetrical with respect to $t_1$ and $t_2$", but is supposed to be an *even function of its single variable* $t$. This implies that the composed function $$g(t_1,t_2):=f(t_2-t_1)$$ of two variables is symmetric with respect to $t_1$ and $t_2$. It follows that the integral of $g$ over the square $Q:=[0,T]^2$ is twice the integral over the part below the main diagonal. We therefore have
$$\int_Q f(t_2-t_1)\>{\rm d}(t_1,t_2)=\int_Q g(t_1,t_2)\>{\rm d}(t_1,t_2)=2\int_0^T\int_0^{t_1} f(t_2-t_1)\>dt_2\>dt_1\ .$$
Now
$$\int_0^{t_1} f(t_2-t_1)\>dt_2=\int_0^{t_1} f(t_1-t_2)\>dt_2=\int_0^{t_1}f(t)\>dt\ .$$
One more thing: Please don't use the letter $k$ for a continuous variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving my problem.I am a little curious about your statement  " not symmetrical with respect to t_1 and t_2, but an even function of its single variable t". What is the difference between the two? actually I want to use this property for the following integral and the only information I have is the symmetry of function $f(t_2-t_1)$. Can I still use the result in this type of integral? $\int_{0}^{t}dt_1 \int_{0}^{t} dt_2 exp{-at_1}exp{-bt_2}f(t_2-t_1)$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is not a function of two variables so I guess you mean $f$ is even $f(-x)=f(x)$. Change variables to $\{t_1,k\}=\{t_1,t_2-t_1\}$, Jacobian is 1.

You get 
$$\int_{0}^t dt_1\int_{-t}^t f(k)dk$$ since $f$ is even negative $k$ give exactly the same contribution as positive $k$ so that is the same as $$2\int_0^t dt_1\int_0^t  f(k) dk$$